# A neutral something as "working" (not imply correctness or not)

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I occasionally need to describe that something works but that it does not necessarily does so correctly. To give some background, it's mostly to do with software - If I'm given the task to investigate some odd behaviour, I sometimes find that a piece of code "works", because the instructions given to the computer are logically consistent (in other words, there is no bug), however, it may not produce the desired result because the instructions are wrong (e.g., initial design was flawed, or it the system is wrongly configured) or because the circumstances were abnormal (e.g., could be an edge case or a failure outside of this piece of software). At any rate, it usually means that the code investigation part is complete and more research is needed but code-wise it's the functionality is consistent with how it is supposed to work. Whether or not it is supposed to work is a different question.

I've used "operational" before but it does not seem to represent the idea well enough.

Comment: It works as designed but not necessarily as intended?

Comment: "works as designed" "not a bug" "Check inputs"

Comment: @KristinaLopez that sounds about right, in fact. If you can add this as an answer, I'll wait for a day or two and probably accept it unless something more suitable comes up.

Comment: The software _runs_, but not necessarily correctly. This word could be used to describe an engine or a machine as well.

Comment: @SrJoven not precisely - it could work as designed, but the design might be wrong, for example, the program is fed numbers 2 and 3 and produces 5 (2+3) but the correct output is 6 (2*3). Whether or not it is a bug may depend on clarifying the requirements - in the previous example, the instructions for *a*+*b* are consistent with the output, but the output is still incorrect. Or it could be a different reason. I'm more looking at saying "at this stage, I know it's not faulty code".

Comment: At first I thought you meant something that did the intended job but not in the most elegant way (and which was therefore perhaps "sub-optimal), but now it sounds like you mean that the code is internally consistent and without bugs, but not "working" in the sense of answering the right question.  I guess you don't want to call it "bugless"?

Comment: @vstrong yes, you are correct. I only want to make a small correction - it may, in fact, be answering the correct question. At this point it is not known - so, the question might need to be clarified.

Comment: I think it might.  Because I would suggest different words for "doing the right job but not in the best way" and "not doing the right job, but not because of a bug within the program."  I am also struggling with the idea that the program might be performing the intended job yet also behaving oddly.  As a non-programmer, I would think that the assigned job would include no odd behavior, such that odd behavior means the job is not being properly done.

Comment: @vstrong to give a (somewhat contrived) example of a program behaving oddly, let's say you have some sort of text editing program, and you want to put a heading in your text. A heading is formatted to be a larger font and be bold, but you also want to make the heading blue. However, when you make it blue it loses the size and boldness. So, normally, you'd expect that you can add the two styles together but it turns out the software does not allow to add different styles to headings. It could be because it was designed for all headings to be consistent, or it could have been an oversight.

Comment: @vld, thanks.  I would almost say that such a program is technically sound but "miscalibrated" to the request/desired output.  But frankly I'm not sure that's "a real word."

Comment: It plays all the correct notes, not necessarily in the correct order.

Comment: You correctly put _works_ in scare-quotes here; [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work) gives the default meaning for this sense as << 
2 (of a machine or system) function ... properly or effectively. >> (actually,  << 
2(of a machine or system) function, especially properly or effectively. >> ).  I'd say that if it doesn't produce the desired result, it **doesn't** work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"The code is functioning as designed but not necessarily as intended."***  Additional, specific examples can then be appended to this initial assessment of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something that doesn't work as you would want it to or that it is partially complete?

Maybe the word 'Stopgap' or 'makeshift' is better in that case? Meaning just a temporary fix to a problem.

So you'd use it this way:

'*This is only a stopgap until I find something better.*'

'*This is just a makeshift measure until I find a better solution.*'

Comment: "You mean something that doesn't work as you would want it to or that it is partially complete?" No, at least not necessarily - it could be a finished phase. I certainly don't mean to convey "unfinishedness" quality.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, yes, the words I suggested are good too.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary, alpha or beta (also heard of red or blue cut), rough cut, (stop-gap already given and best so far), holder and temporary.

Comment: I take this all back.   I misread the question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"Works as designed, but design is flawed."

Comment: This simply restates the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest specific what phase the problem was introduced, e.g. issue escaped from *requirements phase* or issues escaped from *design phase*.

Here is a explanation from Pragmatic Software Testing: Becoming an Effective and Efficient Test Professional By Rex Black
[image: Test phases]